# Does readthedocs behave differently if a build branch has a slash in it?

Tags: git, github, read-the-docs

I am using `readthedocs` to build documentation for my [project](https://nrcascadesim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I currently have two branches `docstest` and `feature/sphinx` with identical content being parsed by `readthedocs`. You can view each of these by clicking the version tab on the sidebar from the docs frontpage that I linked.

I have been struggling to get `feature/sphinx` to render correctly, in particular it seems like (maybe?) when I use `feature/sphinx` it expects the source tree to start in `docs/` rather than `docs/source`. Currently all the source is in `docs/source` like in [this example](https://obscura.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). This leads to `feature/sphinx` not rendering correctly (i.e. the ToC is not rendered at all). Is it because the branch name has a slash in it?

Also neither branch seems to render the side-bar correctly. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I'd follow up in the issue tracker: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/search?q=branch+with+slash&type=issues

Comment: @StevePiercy done,  see here: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/8633